# Integrating JMeter with ZAP tool

Tags: jmeter, zap

I want to automate JMeter with ZAP tool.

I have the JMeter script recorded with all the API calls and which is working fine. Now I want to integrate JMeter with ZAP. Im running JMeter like below using same port of ZAP. But couldn't see any interaction with ZAP and no report. How to integrate JMeter with ZAP?

jmeter -H localhost -P 8000 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl

Next question is which is the option should I select in the ZAP? Automated scan or Manual Explore.

Answer (score 1):

2 processes cannot listen on the same port.
You need to configure jmeter to proxy through ZAP. A quick search found https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server but I havnt tried it.

Once you have that set up correctly then any API calls made with jmeter will appear in ZAP. That will give you passive scanning. You will need to use active scanning in order to attack your application.